# NullPointerException with a getter on a Long but not with a BigDecimal

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, long-integer, getter

This is my first question after many years of using this great forum and hence the first time I didn't find an answer to my issue :(

I'm getting a strange behaviour working with `BigDecimal` and `Long`: for the first one I’m not getting a `NullPointerException` but I do with the second.

My code is as following:

```
if (aggregate != null) {
    existingAggregates.setAmtExpect((aggregate.getAmtRecv());

    existingAggregates.setNbTrxExpect(aggregate.getNbTrxRecv());
}
```

Where aggregate and existingAggregates are of the same Object type Aggregate (I shortened the original class but in fact it is a Hibernate entity (if full version is needed, keep me posted :)

```
public class Aggregate implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal amtExpect;

    private Long nbTrxExpect;

    public BigDecimal getAmtExpect() {
        return amtExpect;
    }

    public void setAmtExpect(BigDecimal amtExpect) {
        this.amtExpect = amtExpect;
    }

    public Long getNbTrxExpect() {
        return nbTrxExpect;
    }

    public void setNbTrxExpect(Long nbTrxExpect) {
       this.nbTrxExpect = nbTrxExpect;
    }

}
```

My problem happens when aggregate is not null, but when the two members `amtExpect` and `nbTrxExpect` are null.

Everything is doing fine with the `getAmtRecv()` but an `NullPointerException` is thrown with `getNbTrxRecv()`.

I would understand if both would throw an NPE but I really don't get it why it only happens with the Long member :s

I searched the forum, but couldn't find any good explanation for me. Is it because of Autoboxing or something like that? I’m lost...

Anyway, To be able to run this code, I changed it like below:

```
if (aggregate != null) {
    existingAggregates.setAmtExpect((aggregate.getAmtRecv() != null) ? aggregate.getAmtRecv() : BigDecimal.ZERO);

    existingAggregates.setNbTrxExpect((aggregate.getNbTrxRecv() != null) ? aggregate.getNbTrxRecv() : BigDecimal.ZERO.longValue());
}
```

It's working, but I still don't get it what's going with the first version of my code.

Many thanks,
Noshitheel

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace in here? I'm just curious as given with your current code, it should not happen.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that it is `void setNbTrxExpect(Long nbTrxExpect)` and not `void setNbTrxExpect(long nbTrxExpect)`? I'd have guessed this was an auto-unboxing error.

Comment: You seem to be deriving the long value from the BigDecimal, so why store the long value at all? Something is fishy here

Comment: Are you sure that there are no fields/variables declared `long` anywhere, instead of `Long`?  If so, that would kick in autounboxing and lead to the NPEs you're describing.  (But as written I can't see why this would cause a problem.)

Comment: @kucing_terbang i tried to reproduce the case by putting back the old code and now it works :s

Comment: @Andy Turner yes, i'm 100% sure there's no long used

Comment: @fge i don't understand what you mean, could you please explain? thanks

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle nope, i didn't used any long, but now i know if i do once i'll have to double check :)

Comment: There must be something in the code that you've not posted, because there are only so many ways that `existingAggregates.setNbTrxExpect(aggregate.getNbTrxRecv());` can throw an NPE.

Comment: Indeed @Andy Turner, or maybe i changed something since yesterday (yeah i spend half a day on this). Anyway, for safety, i will leave the double checks to prevent any exception. I've inherited that code, but for the next time, i'll took care of all you remarks